# enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift2

```
[parsedDict 
   enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse
                           usingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
```

This is in OBJC

How to write same line in swift

Comment: what's hard with that ? just do it.

Comment: what's the purpose of reverse enumeration for a dictionary? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, the pure Swift version

```
let parsedDict = ["key": "value", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"]
for (key, value) in parsedDict
{
    print("key: \(key), value:\(value)")
}
```

Since [the effect of `NSEnumerationOptions.Reverse` is undefined for NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-260167), we can safely ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that:

```
let parsedDict : NSDictionary = ["key": "value", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"]

parsedDict.enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions(NSEnumerationOptions.Reverse, usingBlock: { (key, value, stop) -> Void in
    print("key: \(key), value:\(value)")
})
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer got a down vote.  I've just checked it in a Playground and it works as advertised.